# Security certificate unavailable on all sites

Tags: ssl, windows-7, virtualbox

I have **Windows 7** installed on a **VirtualBox** machine with bridged network. All the websites (Both on Firefox and IE) give me the **This Connection is Untrusted/There is a problem with this website's security certificate.**

I also have problems accessing the NuGet repository from Visual Studio (which is using SSL over HTTP, so I guess is the same issue). It also looks like the shared VBox folder is "untrusted" as I cannot run T4 template from that location in VS.

Any idea of the possible causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual machine had the TimeOffset property set, therefore was backdating the system of few months, causing the SSL certificates to be all expired. Removing the date offset everything is fine.